# Check if the user's input is valid

Tags: python, html, flask

Users are entering their address and age. When the find button is hit, it will display the inputs. However, for the case where input is not valid, I would like to add an error message.

How do I check if the input is not valid and gives an error message? I want my error message to be on the same page as where values are input. The code does not work correctly.

```html
 <div class = "Information">
  <h2>Your Infomation</h2>
  <form action="" method=post>
    if (error){
      <p id="error"><strong></strong>{{error}}
    }
    <div id = "address">
      <label>address</label>
      <input type=text name=address value="{{request.form.address}}">
    </div>
    <div id = "age">
      <label>age</label>
      <input type=text name=age value="{{request.form.age}}">
    </div>
    <div class = "Input">
      <a href="/results">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" value="find" >Find!</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```python
@app.route('/results',methods=['GET','POST'])
def result():
    error = None;
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['age'] != '14':
            error='You did not enter proper values'
    return render_template('template.html',error=error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper Jinja syntax to render templates:

```
{% if error %}<p id="error">{{ error }}</p>{% endif %}
```

---

Beyond that, the button you've added to your form doesn't actually submit the form, as you've given it the "button" type rather than the "submit" type and have wrapped it in an anchor for some reason.  Replace the contents of `<div class="Input">` with:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="find">Find!</button>
```